# Path from the user-space application to the GPU. X server vs. Direct rendering

Tags: linux, x11, opengl, graphic-card, drm

Are these hierarchies correct for applications (or some part of) that use OpenGL directly(i.e not GLX) and for those which use XLib in linux?

OpenGL:

```
OpenGL --> libmesa --> libdrm --> Kernel DRM --> (Nvidia - AMD) DRM driver --> Driver --> GPU
```

X11:

```
XLib --> Event Queue --> Xserver (Xorg or XFree86) --> GLX --> DDX (Nvidia - AMD) --> (Nvidia - AMD) DRM driver  --> Driver --> GPU
```

Or if not, what are the correct orders?

*These are merely my opinions. But I would appreciate any suggestion to the inaccuracies.

Comment: No (you can use both without nvidia.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor What do you mean by "without nvidia"? (Joke or serious)?

Comment: I don't have nvidia on my machine, but I have openGL and X11.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor So no problem with the hierarchies ?

Comment: I have no Idea.